# how to move button to left

Tags: css, dart

I am using angular2dart components and do not know, how to move the button on left side.
[image]

here is html:

```
 <div class="forms">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginCtrl="ngForm">
            <div>
                <material-input type="text"
                                class="login"
                                required
                                floatingLabel
                                label="User"
                                [(ngModel)]="login.user"
                                ngControl="user"
                                #user="ngForm" ></material-input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <material-input
                        class="login"
                        type="password"
                        floatingLabel label="Password"
                        [(ngModel)]="login.password">
                </material-input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <material-input
                        class="login"
                        type="text"
                        floatingLabel
                        label="Language"
                        [(ngModel)]="login.language">

                </material-input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <material-button raised class="btn-blue">Login</material-button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

here is the css:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container .row {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    padding: 20px;
}

.container .row .image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2D3E50;
}

.container .row .forms {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.container .row .forms .input {
    width: 256px;
}

.btn-blue {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

material-input.login {
    width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question that builds above dialog or panel.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML around of that what you added - the whole card shown in your screenshot

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: What CSS is applied to `<div class="forms">`?

Comment: Just update the whole css.

Comment: Is "box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);" the shadow of the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, it is like a login panel.

Comment: Did Sanches suggestion not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add css to login button

```
{
width:auto;
float:left;
}
```

and class row to div which wrapped on login button.